# How to stop a program from maximizing after using Alt + Tab on Windows

Tags: windows-10

Let's say I play a game and in the meantime I use Alt + Tab or I switch to a virtual desktop using Ctrl + Win + Arrows. The game has a system which maximizes it when the match is found and it constantly switches my virtual desktops or maximizes when I am doing something else.

**Is there a way to prevent programs from maximizing on their own and let user switch to them only using Alt + Tab/Ctrl + Win + Arrows?**